# Working on a problem to find the lowest number at which we can pay off debt in a year. Answer is a bit off

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking a course on edx and trying to solve a problem using bisection to calculate a monthly payment at which we can pay off the debt in a year. I have coded a solution but the results are a bit off than expected. Code is below. Answer code shared by edx is also listed beneath. Can you please share why my code is not giving same results? I am trying to get to to 2 decimal places accuracy.

```
balance=float(input('balance  = '))
annualInterestRate=float(input('annualInterestRate = '))
 

remainingbalance=balance

low=float(remainingbalance/12)
high=float(remainingbalance*((1+(annualInterestRate/12))**12)/12.0)


if remainingbalance>0.01 or remaningbalance<0.01:
  remainingbalance=balance
  increment=round(float((high+low)/2), 2)

  for i in range(1, 13):
   unpaidbalance=remainingbalance-increment
   interest=(annualInterestRate/12) * unpaidbalance
   remainingbalance=round(unpaidbalance + interest, 2)

  if remainingbalance>0.01:
     low=increment
  elif remainingbalance<-0.01:
      high=increment
  
print('Lowest Payment: ', increment)
```

Sample code for solution provided by edx

```
init_balance = balance
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
lower = init_balance/12
upper = (init_balance * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)**12)/12.0
epsilon = 0.03

while abs(balance) > epsilon:
    monthlyPaymentRate = (upper + lower)/2
    balance = init_balance
    for i in range(12):
        balance = balance - monthlyPaymentRate + ((balance - monthlyPaymentRate) * monthlyInterestRate)
    if balance > epsilon:
        lower = monthlyPaymentRate
    elif balance < -epsilon:
        upper = monthlyPaymentRate
    else:
        break
print('Lowest Payment:', round(monthlyPaymentRate, 2))
```

My Code Results:
balance  = 320000
annualInterestRate = 0.2
Lowest Payment:  29591.88

Edx Results:
balance  = 320000
annualInterestRate = 0.2
Lowest Payment: 29157.09

Comment: Are you sure you mean `remainingbalance>0.01 or remaningbalance<0.01` and not `remainingbalance>0.01 or remaningbalance<-0.01`?  This loop only breaks when remainingbalance is precisely 1 penny.

Comment: Yup. We need accuracy of payment to be made to a single cent

Comment: Reread my comment.  I think you misunderstood what I was writing or what your code does.  Why do you want remainingBalance == .01 precisely, which is what your code does.

Comment: Hey Frank! Thank you for looking into it. It would be better if we can get remainingbalance==0. We have to be accurate to a single cent so even if we make payments such that remainingbalance==0 that is fine as well. 

Secondly one of the problem in above code was that I was using if loop instead of while loop

Comment: Precisely my point.  You want the balance to end up between -.01 and .01.  That's not what you've written.

Comment: Yes! thank you! It makes sense now! It should be -0.01 and 0.01!